# How to select the maximum of each type

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a table that describes how many FISH, VEG, OR meat are in each tray.

```
 tray  | qty | type
-------+-----+-------
     1 |   5 | FISH
     2 |   6 | VEG
     2 |   2 | FISH
     2 |   5 | MEAT
     3 |   8 | VEG
     3 |   3 | FISH
     3 |   9 | MEAT
     4 |  10 | MEAT
```

Lets call this table R (it is a sub table that I created in my query).

What I want is a table that says which tray has the highest number of each type like this:

```
  type | tray
-------+------
  FISH |  1 
   VEG |  3
  MEAT |  4
```

I tried to write the following query

```
SELECT type AS type1, tray
FROM (SELECT ... bla bla) AS R
WHERE R.qty IN (SELECT MAX(qty) FROM R WHERE type = type1);
```

the error is that R doesn't exist, how do I solve this?

Comment: I tried your query, it works fine (I assume that your table name is `R`).

Comment: @miselking R is not a table in my database. R is created in the query. I updated my post to show what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using window functions:

```
select r.type, r.tray
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by qty desc) as seqnum
      from r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Is there any other solutions? I am suppose to be able to write this with constructs that I have learned (never seen this partition before)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT otr.tray, otr._type, _qty 
FROM 
    Your_Table otr 
    JOIN ( 
        SELECT _type, MAX(qty) _qty 
        FROM Your_Table 
        GROUP BY _type 
    ) A ON A._type = otr._type AND _qty = qty
```

Answer (score 0):

[distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first.

```
select distinct on (tray, type) *
from r
order by tray, type, qty desc
```

If `distinct on` is not allowed as it is Postgresql only then do a self join:

```
select tray, type, qty
from
    r 
    join (
        select type, max(qty) as qty
        from r
        group by type
    ) s using (type, qty)
```